# Intel 7260 wireless card no longer working

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

My laptop is the Acer Aspire 5750 and I have an aftermarket Intel 7260 card in it.

After installing Manjaro, I realized that my wifi card was not working. I installed Ubuntu later, and had the same problem.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to make this post to share knowledge as it is something that I have fixed with the help of [tbg on Manjaro Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/u/tbg).

After going through a process of troubleshooting [(on this Manjaro forum post)](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/intel-7260-wireless-card-driver-no-longer-working/141878/18) with the advice of tbg I blacklisted the `btusb` and `acer_wmi` in the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file. After I blacklisted the module the wifi started working.

When I installed Ubuntu, the wifi stopped working so again I blacklisted the `btusb` and `acer_wmi` modules and after rebooting the wifi started working.

Blacklisting a module prevents it being loaded into the kernel at boot time. To do this, either edit the main file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, or make a new file in the same directory with the suffix `.conf`, for example `sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/wireless-fix-blacklist.conf` In either case, add a line for each module to be blacklisted like this, optionally with a comment to remind your future self why you did this:

```
# these prevent wireless from working
blacklist btusb
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Comment: While it is perfectly fine and appreciated to [answer your own question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) in order to share knowledge or because you simply found the solution yourself later, please adhere to the site's Question & Answer format. In other words, describe only the problem in your question, and put the solution in the answer post. Putting both in the question and/or adding an answer without actual content like this one is not okay. Please edit your posts accordingly. Thank you :)

Comment: @Byte Commander♦ thank you for letting me know about the correct format for answering my own questions  I'll adhere to the guidelines in the future :).

Comment: @Zanna ♦ thank you for editing the posts to the guidelines. (Before I even managed to wake up)

Comment: You are most welcome :) Thank you very much for taking the time to share your solution here.