# very weak signal for old routers, can't connect at all for new routers with intel 7260 wifi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi signal is extremely weak since I reinstalled my operating system. I need to stay very close to the router in order to make it work.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, an Intel 7260 wireless adapter, kernel 5.15.0-52-generic, firmware version: 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode.

For all the details of my setup, here is the result of the wireless info script [found here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos):  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/r8tJ55GqMY/

I tried some solutions found here, but so far, none of them worked.
I tried to modify iwlwifi configuration (11n_disable=1, power_save=0, bt_coex_active=0, swcrypto=1) as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/660158).
I also tried to blacklist modules as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256923).

It seems that a lot of people have the same problem, and sitll I have not found a definitive solution.

EDIT: My computer cannot connect at all to networks with more modern routers, even if signal strength is strong. So I can see the network and its signal strength but can't connect. It seems that I can only connect to older router models and with low distance.

Restarting network manager by `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` did not solve my problem either.

Comment: Is your router set to auto channel select (bad) or a fixed channel (good)?

Comment: Does running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` improve your wifi signal?

Comment: @chili555 how can I check that?

Comment: @stumblebee unfortunately no. I will update my post accordingly

Comment: Do you have administrative access to the router? Check there.

Comment: @chili555 I checked and it is automatic. However, I do not think that this is the problem, as my laptop used to work with these routers before. Also, I cannot change the settings of the router everywhere where I use my laptop, so I need to find a way to make it work whhen the router is set to auto. All other laptops can manage, so I guess mine could too.